# Como obtener el ultimo dia de cada mes en datepicker bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, laravel, datepicker

tengo esta duda y no encuentro alguna solucion, en mi datepicker tengo que seleccionar solo el mes y año pero solo me da el dia 1 de cada mes, pero lo que requiero es el ultimo dia de ese mes que ya seleccione.

mi input

```
<input
    required
    id="datepickerto"
    type="text"
    name="from"
    class="form-control"
    placeholder="Desde:"
    autocomplete="off">
```

y mi Script

```
$('#datepickerto').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        language: 'es',
        format: 'yyyy-mm',
        viewMode: "months",
        minViewMode: "months",
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero revisa los id de tu form, ya que en el input el id es `datepickerfrom` y en el script tienes `datepickerto`

Si ya tienes arreglado esto, puedes utilizar la libreria `Carbon` para establecer los días que necesitas

```
$from = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m', $request->get('from'))->startOfMonth();
$to = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m', $request->get('to'))->endOfMonth();
```